# how to get value of Material-ui auto-complete in react.js

Tags: reactjs, material-ui

how to get value of Material-ui auto-complete in react.js.

I tired

```
productName: this.refs.productName.value 
productName: this.refs.productName.getValue()
```

both are not working

```
<AutoComplete
          hintText="Product Name"
         // filter={AutoComplete.noFilter}
         // filter={AutoComplete.fuzzyFilter}
          filter={AutoComplete.caseInsensitiveFilter}
          openOnFocus={true}
          name="productName"
           ref="productName"
            value={this.props.signUpState.productName}
            dataSource={datasource}
             floatingLabelText="Product Name"
             hintText="Product Name"
             onChange={this.props._inputHandler}
       //   onUpdateInput={this.props.signUpState.handleUpdateInput}
       //   dataSourceConfig={dataSourceConfig}
        />
```

Comment: I didnt get any solution still

Answer (score 1):

this.refs.productName.state.searchText

alternative,

use onUpdateInput prop.

```
<Autocomplete
onUpdateInput={this.handleUpdateInput.bind(this)}
/>
handleUpdateInput = (searchText) => {
  console.log(searchText)
}
```

Comment: Thanks for your answer, I will try it